# Jenkins : How to create a view based on multiple jobs results?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have multiple jobs running on Jenkins, with some outputs/graphs to measures code quality (warning, unit test result, indicator plots).

How can I create a view that summarize all these informations on one page ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script that uses the [Jenkins Remote Access API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) to query the status of various jobs and print a summary.

Then, you can run this script itself as Jenkins job. The summary will appear in the build log of the job.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to use the [dashboard view](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View)

The following are fully integrated :

- joblist
- warning
- cppunit test result (each job should publish its result as a post-build action)
- cppcheck result (each job should publish its result as a post-build action)
- plot display (using the image portlet)

It still dont know how to display Doxygen link...